# Prevent html tag creation during html() using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a string `"<F1>"` and whenever I add it as html to a particular div using jquery's html(), as

```
var str = "<F1>";

$("div").html(str);
```

It generates html for div as

```
"<f1></f1>"
```

But I dont want such tag creation.

I need to have div with html as

```
"&lt;F1&gt;"
```

It will be appreciated if somebody guide me, to achieve this. :(

Comment: If you need to escape the input string for some reason, please show the full code. In the case you have presented `text()` is the way to go, and there's no need to use `html()`. I have updated my answer with a solution that allows you to use `.html()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

```
var str = "<F1>";

$("div").text(str);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6942a/

To escape the HTML entities in `str` and use `.html()` you can do the following:

```
var str = "<F1>";
str = $("<div/>").text(str).html();

$("div").html(str);
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6942a/3/

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird, the jsfiddle link you shared is something different and not related what OP asked. Please check.

Comment: I need to do with html() and the string is not fixed. It is a captured text from input element.

Comment: If you wish to use html(), then you need to ensure the input is valid html, and allow tags to be there. That's what html() is for.

Comment: jQuery Angry Bird - that's what the OP will get with `.text(str)`. The HTML of the div will be `&lt;F1&gt;` . See http://jsfiddle.net/6942a/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="ADD">
```

jQuery :

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
      var text = $('input[type=text]').val();
      text =text.replace('<','&#60');
      text =text.replace('>','&#62');
      $("div").html(text);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PHvYK/465/)**

For more information see **[html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)**

Comment: I am having editor say text area, in which I am adding text as "<F1>" and i am using its value to as html string to set in "div". can u plz help me for such scenario?

Comment: In that case see what @Ketola suggested in his answer.

Comment: Sorry, but i need to go with html() :( because it is used further for other functionality. Can there be any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = '<f1>'; 
var res = str.replace("<", "&lt;");
res=res.replace(">", "&gt;");
$("div").text(res);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6942a/2/)